# compile pstricks: ps2pdf doesn't work

Tags: pstricks, texstudio, ps2pdf

I would like to revisit an old question, namely how to compile pstricks code properly. I tried to use the dvi-ps-pdf chain with the latex compiler within texstudio but it failed because ps2pdf seems to get stuck. I am using the latest version of MacOS (Mojave) as well as TeXStudio with TeXLive.

I also tried to compile with XeLaTeX and to use shell escape with pdflatex but both didn't work either.

I would be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: Do you have Ghostscript installed?

Comment: "seems to get stuck"  doesn't give enough information for anyone to help. What error did you get?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not receiving a particular error, rather nothing happens at all. The system keeps running for a long time and I terminated the compiling after a few minutes.

Comment: @HerbSchulz No, actually not. Should I install it?

Comment: which loops ps2pdf or latex?  ps2pdf is just a wrapper around ghostscript it shouldn't hang if you don't have gs installed., You could post a small complete document and then we can check if there are any postscript errors. You could write a postscript loop in pstricks that would hang a postscript interpreter , so it could be a postscript error in your pstricks input....

Comment: @Hazards : ’ps2pdf` is part of Ghostscript so you need to install it. How did you install TeX Live? Did you use the MacTeX installer? If so you should already have Ghostscript installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PStricks doesn't compile anymore since MacTeX 2021 upgrade on Mac M1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591533/pstricks-doesnt-compile-anymore-since-mactex-2021-upgrade-on-mac-m1)

Answer (score 0):

You must add the -dAllOWPSTRANSPARENCY flag to the ps2pdf run as find in [PStricks doesn't compile anymore since MacTeX 2021 upgrade on Mac M1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591533/pstricks-doesnt-compile-anymore-since-mactex-2021-upgrade-on-mac-m1)
thanks to Herb schulzt. it's ok in texstudio now for me.