# auto-pst-pdf not compiling any more (after a year or so)

Tags: shell-escape, auto-pst-pdf

Some background:

Before May 2020 (or even earlier), the code runs fine without any problem.
Then I digged up the project and with to update some contents today,
it would not compile any more.

Here is a **MWE**.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,UTF8,twoside]{ctexart}
\ctexset{today=old}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[flushleft]{paralist}[2013/06/09] % VERY IMPORTANT
\usepackage{asymptote}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{blue}}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    lmargin=1.5cm,
    rmargin=1.5cm,
    tmargin=1.8cm,
    bmargin=1.5cm,
    headheight=24pt
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfsuppressptexinfo=-1

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by-nc-nd},
    version={4.0}
]{doclicense}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \usepackage{lastpage}
% \usepackage{atenddvi}   %multiple last page
\usepackage[user]{zref} %multiple last page

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% -- compile
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}            %% added for pdflatex, use pdflatex -shell-escape $(NAME_PART).tex
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}   %% added for pdflatex, use pdflatex -shell-escape $(NAME_PART).tex
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
%% \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %% changes font to sans-serif

\newlength{\qspace}
\setlength{\qspace}{20pt}
\newcounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}
%%
%%
\newenvironment{question}%
{\vspace{\qspace}
    \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries 1\quad][10]%
    \setcounter{enumi}{\value{qnumber}}%
    \item
}{
    \end{enumerate}
    \filbreak % cool to know
    \stepcounter{qnumber}
}
%%
\newenvironment{questionparts}[1][1]%
{
    \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries (i)]%
    \setcounter{enumii}{#1}
    \addtocounter{enumii}{-1}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{5mm}
    \setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
}{
    \end{enumerate}
}
%%
\begin{asydef}
    import markers;
    import geometry;
    import graph;
    usepackage("amsmath");
\end{asydef}

%%% Document begins %%%

\begin{document}

\begin{question}

A plane makes an acute angle $\alpha$ with the horizontal. A box in the shape of a cube is fixed  onto  the plane  in such a way that four of its edges are horizontal and two of its sides are vertical.


A uniform rod of length $2L$ and weight $W$ rests  with its lower end at $A$ on the bottom of the box and its upper end at $B$ on a side of the box, as shown in the diagram below.  The vertical plane containing the rod  is parallel to the vertical sides of the box and cuts the lowest edge of the box at $O$. The rod makes an acute angle~$\beta$ with the side of the box at $B$.

The coefficients of friction between the rod and the box at the two points of contact are both $\tan \gamma$, where $0<   \gamma<\frac12\pi$.
%The  frictional force on the rod at $A$ acts toward $O$, 
%and the frictional force on the rod at~$B$
%acts away from $O$.

The rod is in limiting equilibrium, with the end at $A$  on the point of slipping in the direction away from $O$ and the end at $B$ on the point of slipping towards $O$. Given that $\alpha < \beta$, show that $\beta = \alpha + 2\gamma$. 

[{\bf Hint}: You may find it helpful to take moments about the midpoint of 
the rod.]
\vspace{-1.5cm}
\begin{center}
\newrgbcolor{zzttqq}{0.6 0.2 0}
\newrgbcolor{xdxdff}{0.49 0.49 1}
\psset{xunit=6mm  ,yunit=6mm  }
\begin{pspicture*}(-8.3,-6.72)(15.56,8.3)
\psset{xunit=0.8cm,yunit=0.8cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\pspolygon[linewidth=1.2pt,
%linecolor=zzttqq,
](0,-3)(-1.55,2.8)(4.24,4.35)(5.87,-1.41)
\psline(-2.54,-3   )(12,-3)
\psline(-2.46,-3.62)(11.59,0.11)
%\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=zzttqq](0,-3)(-1.55,2.8)
%\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=zzttqq](-1.55,2.8)(4.24,4.35)
%\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=zzttqq](4.24,4.35)(5.87,-1.41)
%\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=zzttqq](5.87,-1.41)(0,-3)
\rput[tl](2.6 ,-2.4 ){$ A $}
\rput[tl](-1.8 ,1.6){$ B $}
\rput[tl](-0.2,-3.15 ){$ O $}
\rput[tl](1.4 ,-2.7){$ \alpha $}
\rput[tl](-0.8,0.8){$ \beta $}
\psline[linewidth=2.3pt](-1.20,1.52)(2.8,-2.22)
\pscustom[linecolor=black,fillcolor=zzttqq,fillstyle=none,opacity=0.0]{\parametricplot{-0.0127510246967992202}{0.2471697861109875}{1*1.84*cos(t)+0*1.84*sin(t)+-0.0|0*1.84*cos(t)+1*1.84*sin(t)+-2.98}\lineto(0,-2.99)\closepath}
\pscustom[linecolor=black,fillcolor=zzttqq,fillstyle=none,opacity=0.0]{\parametricplot{4.974188368183839}{5.533030852440859}{1*1.45*cos(t)+0*1.45*sin(t)+-1.21|0*1.45*cos(t)+1*1.45*sin(t)+1.52}\lineto(-1.21,1.52)\closepath}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{center}

\end{question}

\end{document}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,UTF8,twoside]{ctexart}
\ctexset{today=old}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[flushleft]{paralist}[2013/06/09] % VERY IMPORTANT
\usepackage{asymptote}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{blue}}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    lmargin=1.5cm,
    rmargin=1.5cm,
    tmargin=1.8cm,
    bmargin=1.5cm,
    headheight=24pt
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfsuppressptexinfo=-1

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by-nc-nd},
    version={4.0}
]{doclicense}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \usepackage{lastpage}
% \usepackage{atenddvi}   %multiple last page
\usepackage[user]{zref} %multiple last page

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% -- compile
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}            %% added for pdflatex, use pdflatex -shell-escape $(NAME_PART).tex
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}   %% added for pdflatex, use pdflatex -shell-escape $(NAME_PART).tex
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
%% \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %% changes font to sans-serif

\newlength{\qspace}
\setlength{\qspace}{20pt}
\newcounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}
%%
%%
\newenvironment{question}%
{\vspace{\qspace}
    \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries 1\quad][10]%
    \setcounter{enumi}{\value{qnumber}}%
    \item
}{
    \end{enumerate}
    \filbreak % cool to know
    \stepcounter{qnumber}
}
%%
\newenvironment{questionparts}[1][1]%
{
    \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries (i)]%
    \setcounter{enumii}{#1}
    \addtocounter{enumii}{-1}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{5mm}
    \setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
}{
    \end{enumerate}
}
%%
\begin{asydef}
    import markers;
    import geometry;
    import graph;
    usepackage("amsmath");
\end{asydef}

%%% Document begins %%%

\begin{document}

\begin{question}

A plane makes an acute angle $\alpha$ with the horizontal. A box in the shape of a cube is fixed  onto  the plane  in such a way that four of its edges are horizontal and two of its sides are vertical.


A uniform rod of length $2L$ and weight $W$ rests  with its lower end at $A$ on the bottom of the box and its upper end at $B$ on a side of the box, as shown in the diagram below.  The vertical plane containing the rod  is parallel to the vertical sides of the box and cuts the lowest edge of the box at $O$. The rod makes an acute angle~$\beta$ with the side of the box at $B$.

The coefficients of friction between the rod and the box at the two points of contact are both $\tan \gamma$, where $0<   \gamma<\frac12\pi$.
%The  frictional force on the rod at $A$ acts toward $O$, 
%and the frictional force on the rod at~$B$
%acts away from $O$.

The rod is in limiting equilibrium, with the end at $A$  on the point of slipping in the direction away from $O$ and the end at $B$ on the point of slipping towards $O$. Given that $\alpha < \beta$, show that $\beta = \alpha + 2\gamma$. 

[{\bf Hint}: You may find it helpful to take moments about the midpoint of 
the rod.]
\vspace{-1.5cm}
\begin{center}
\newrgbcolor{zzttqq}{0.6 0.2 0}
\newrgbcolor{xdxdff}{0.49 0.49 1}
\psset{xunit=6mm  ,yunit=6mm  }
\begin{pspicture*}(-8.3,-6.72)(15.56,8.3)
\psset{xunit=0.8cm,yunit=0.8cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\pspolygon[linewidth=1.2pt,
%linecolor=zzttqq,
](0,-3)(-1.55,2.8)(4.24,4.35)(5.87,-1.41)
\psline(-2.54,-3   )(12,-3)
\psline(-2.46,-3.62)(11.59,0.11)
%\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=zzttqq](0,-3)(-1.55,2.8)
%\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=zzttqq](-1.55,2.8)(4.24,4.35)
%\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=zzttqq](4.24,4.35)(5.87,-1.41)
%\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=zzttqq](5.87,-1.41)(0,-3)
\rput[tl](2.6 ,-2.4 ){$ A $}
\rput[tl](-1.8 ,1.6){$ B $}
\rput[tl](-0.2,-3.15 ){$ O $}
\rput[tl](1.4 ,-2.7){$ \alpha $}
\rput[tl](-0.8,0.8){$ \beta $}
\psline[linewidth=2.3pt](-1.20,1.52)(2.8,-2.22)
\pscustom[linecolor=black,fillcolor=zzttqq,fillstyle=none,opacity=0.0]{\parametricplot{-0.0127510246967992202}{0.2471697861109875}{1*1.84*cos(t)+0*1.84*sin(t)+-0.0|0*1.84*cos(t)+1*1.84*sin(t)+-2.98}\lineto(0,-2.99)\closepath}
\pscustom[linecolor=black,fillcolor=zzttqq,fillstyle=none,opacity=0.0]{\parametricplot{4.974188368183839}{5.533030852440859}{1*1.45*cos(t)+0*1.45*sin(t)+-1.21|0*1.45*cos(t)+1*1.45*sin(t)+1.52}\lineto(-1.21,1.52)\closepath}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{center}

\end{question}

\end{document}
```

I think the main problem is with `\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}` and `\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}`. I remember last time, there were some testing and tweaking too, but I espeacially made some comments and so I remember how to compile it. And still it failed.

I am using MiKTeX on win10 X64. And my editor is Notepad++ with plugin NppExec to run the compilation.
I also have Ghostscript installed seperately.

At the moment, the best outcome is to have the PDF output, but without any pictures ... so how could I fix this issue.

Some tried compilation

```
pdflatex -shell-escape $(NAME_PART).tex
pdflatex -shell-escape $(NAME_PART).tex
```

Also

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 --enable-write18 $(NAME_PART)
pdflatex -synctex=1 --enable-write18 $(NAME_PART)
```

Comment: Please cite the errors you get

Comment: @daleif It's simply not showing the graphs, and if I look at the temporary -pics file produced, it's blank. Somewhere in the log it's saying ghostscript error of some sort. I will post the screenshot as soon as i got home. Thanks.

Comment: You should list that error. The Ghostscript people have tightened some security so in some cases ghostscript now have to be called with some extra options.

Comment: You should also make your example as small as possible. I get other errors. For example use `article` instead of something that requires a special font. I get the error `%%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dNOSAFER` so that options needs to be given to the ghostscript call.

Comment: Though I cannot get that to work.

Comment: Have a look at this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591561/3929 and see the `auto-pst-pdf` manual as to how one adds that option. Though I cannot get it to work with the version of ghostscript that I have (9.26), the version in MikTeX is different.

Comment: And with current gs I get `Error: /typecheck in --div--`.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I solved it compiling with `xelatex` (no auto-pst-pdf required).

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit daring to use a class like `ctexart` for a work flow requiring dvips. The class loads in dvi-mode `dvipdfmx` drivers everywhere.

Beside this: The `preview` package used by `auto-pst-pdf` has not been adapted to the new shipout code of LaTeX and can easily fail if one of the shipout hooks contains code it doesn't expect.

The following adds some code around `\documentclass` and disables also the shipout code preview doesn't like in your concrete document.

But I would recommend to avoid `auto-pst-pdf` in complex document. Every additional package can add a new incompability. Better create your graphics in external, small documents and include them. The time you gain from the automatic on-the-fly it clearly outweighted by the time lost by debugging the problems of this system.

```
%NEW use dvips driver in dvi mode
\ifnum\pdfoutput=0\relax
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,UTF8,twoside,dvips]{ctexart}
\else
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,UTF8,twoside]{ctexart}
\fi

\ctexset{today=old}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[flushleft]{paralist}[2013/06/09] % VERY IMPORTANT
\usepackage{asymptote}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{3cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{blue}}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
    lmargin=1.5cm,
    rmargin=1.5cm,
    tmargin=1.8cm,
    bmargin=1.5cm,
    headheight=24pt
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfsuppressptexinfo=-1

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by-nc-nd},
    version={4.0}
]{doclicense}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \usepackage{lastpage}
% \usepackage{atenddvi}   %multiple last page
\usepackage[user]{zref} %multiple last page

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% -- compile
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%NEW: pdf option not needed.
\usepackage{pstricks}            %% added for pdflatex, use pdflatex -shell-escape $(NAME_PART).tex
\usepackage[crop=off,cleanup=false]{auto-pst-pdf}   %% added for pdflatex, use pdflatex -shell-escape $(NAME_PART).tex
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
%% \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %% changes font to sans-serif

\newlength{\qspace}
\setlength{\qspace}{20pt}
\newcounter{qnumber}
\setcounter{qnumber}{0}
%%
%%
\newenvironment{question}%
{\vspace{\qspace}
    \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries 1\quad][10]%
    \setcounter{enumi}{\value{qnumber}}%
    \item
}{
    \end{enumerate}
    \filbreak % cool to know
    \stepcounter{qnumber}
}
%%
\newenvironment{questionparts}[1][1]%
{
    \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries (i)]%
    \setcounter{enumii}{#1}
    \addtocounter{enumii}{-1}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{5mm}
    \setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
}{
    \end{enumerate}
}
%%
\begin{asydef}
    import markers;
    import geometry;
    import graph;
    usepackage("amsmath");
\end{asydef}

%NEW avoid clash with hyperref and shipouthook
\makeatletter
\ifPreview
 \let\Hy@FirstPageHook\relax
 \let\Hy@EveryPageAnchor\relax
 \RemoveFromHook{shipout/firstpage}[ctexart]
\fi
\makeatother
%%% Document begins %%%

\begin{document}

\begin{question}

A plane makes an acute angle $\alpha$ with the horizontal. A box in the shape of a cube is fixed  onto  the plane  in such a way that four of its edges are horizontal and two of its sides are vertical.


A uniform rod of length $2L$ and weight $W$ rests  with its lower end at $A$ on the bottom of the box and its upper end at $B$ on a side of the box, as shown in the diagram below.  The vertical plane containing the rod  is parallel to the vertical sides of the box and cuts the lowest edge of the box at $O$. The rod makes an acute angle~$\beta$ with the side of the box at $B$.

The coefficients of friction between the rod and the box at the two points of contact are both $\tan \gamma$, where $0<   \gamma<\frac12\pi$.
%The  frictional force on the rod at $A$ acts toward $O$,
%and the frictional force on the rod at~$B$
%acts away from $O$.

The rod is in limiting equilibrium, with the end at $A$  on the point of slipping in the direction away from $O$ and the end at $B$ on the point of slipping towards $O$. Given that $\alpha < \beta$, show that $\beta = \alpha + 2\gamma$.

[{\bf Hint}: You may find it helpful to take moments about the midpoint of
the rod.]
\vspace{-1.5cm}
\begin{center}
\newrgbcolor{zzttqq}{0.6 0.2 0}
\newrgbcolor{xdxdff}{0.49 0.49 1}
\psset{xunit=6mm  ,yunit=6mm  }
\begin{pspicture*}(-8.3,-6.72)(15.56,8.3)
\psset{xunit=0.8cm,yunit=0.8cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\pspolygon[linewidth=1.2pt,
%linecolor=zzttqq,
](0,-3)(-1.55,2.8)(4.24,4.35)(5.87,-1.41)
\psline(-2.54,-3   )(12,-3)
\psline(-2.46,-3.62)(11.59,0.11)
%\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=zzttqq](0,-3)(-1.55,2.8)
%\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=zzttqq](-1.55,2.8)(4.24,4.35)
%\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=zzttqq](4.24,4.35)(5.87,-1.41)
%\psline[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=zzttqq](5.87,-1.41)(0,-3)
\rput[tl](2.6 ,-2.4 ){$ A $}
\rput[tl](-1.8 ,1.6){$ B $}
\rput[tl](-0.2,-3.15 ){$ O $}
\rput[tl](1.4 ,-2.7){$ \alpha $}
\rput[tl](-0.8,0.8){$ \beta $}
\psline[linewidth=2.3pt](-1.20,1.52)(2.8,-2.22)
\pscustom[linecolor=black,fillcolor=zzttqq,fillstyle=none,opacity=0.0]{\parametricplot{-0.0127510246967992202}{0.2471697861109875}{1*1.84*cos(t)+0*1.84*sin(t)+-0.0|0*1.84*cos(t)+1*1.84*sin(t)+-2.98}\lineto(0,-2.99)\closepath}
\pscustom[linecolor=black,fillcolor=zzttqq,fillstyle=none,opacity=0.0]{\parametricplot{4.974188368183839}{5.533030852440859}{1*1.45*cos(t)+0*1.45*sin(t)+-1.21|0*1.45*cos(t)+1*1.45*sin(t)+1.52}\lineto(-1.21,1.52)\closepath}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{center}

\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I understand the point about having too **many** packages and might be a bit too **complex**. But the point of having ALL of the **packages** is to maintain the **big project** so it can still be used. I am combining some **old** documents and trying to make a collection. Hence still leaving all the packages that I have used in the **MWE**. I will try to stick to everything I have at the moment.

Comment: By the way, it worked flawlessly using ``pdflatex -shell-escape``, and the big compilation just reproduced !! Thanks.