# Transparency Issue on MacTex 2021, previous fix does not work anymore for XeLaTex

Tags: xetex, pstricks, mactex, ghostscript

Recently there was a fix to the problem related to transparency issue on pstricks+ Mactex 2021, which is actually related to Ghostscript ver> 9.53.
It modifies /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/dvipdfmx using some line on dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg

The fix as suggested by Herbert Schulz in:
[PStricks doesn't compile anymore since MacTeX 2021 upgrade on Mac M1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591533/pstricks-doesnt-compile-anymore-since-mactex-2021-upgrade-on-mac-m1)

worked for me few weeks ago, and still works for **latexTRmk**.

But **XeLatexTRmk** engines (in TexShop) does not give the intended result.

I have the following simple code

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% fix PSTricks' transparency setup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{pst-fixtransparency.pro}
  /.setfillconstantalpha.bak /.setfillconstantalpha load def
  /.setstrokeconstantalpha.bak /.setstrokeconstantalpha load def
  /.setalphaisshape.bak /.setalphaisshape load def
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{pst-fixtransparency.sty}
  \AtBeginDvi{
  \special{header=pst-fixtransparency.pro}
  \special{!
    /.setfillconstantalpha /.setfillconstantalpha.bak load def
    /.setstrokeconstantalpha /.setstrokeconstantalpha.bak load def
    /.setalphaisshape /.setalphaisshape.bak load def
    /.setopacityalpha {
      dup .setfillconstantalpha .setstrokeconstantalpha} def
    /.setshapealpha {
      dup .setfillconstantalpha .setstrokeconstantalpha
      true .setalphaisshape} def
  }
}
\end{filecontents}
\RequirePackage{pst-fixtransparency}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d,pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)
   % [Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Times New Roman}
\definecolor{ath}{RGB}{247,246,233}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{ath}

We will plot the surface
$$
\mathbf{r}(u, v)=\langle(2+\sin v) \cos u,(2+\sin v) \sin u, u+\cos v\rangle
$$
\begin{center}
\psset{unit=0.5}
\begin{pspicture}*(-5,-4)(6,14)
        \psset{viewpoint=15 10 15, Decran=20}
        
        \defFunction[algebraic]{hega}(u,v){(2+sin(v))*cos(u)} {(2+sin(v))*sin(u)} {u+cos(v)}
        \psSolid[object=surfaceparametree , base=0  12.6 0 8, color1=Red!50,
        color2=Green!20, inouthue=(color1) (color2), function=hega, linewidth=0.3\pslinewidth, ngrid=40 0.3]
        \axesIIID[linewidth=0.5pt , arrowsize=5pt, arrowinset=0, labelsep=10pt](3,2,9)(6,5,13)
        \psPoint(1,3,6.3){I}
        \uput[r](I){$u$ konstan}

        \psline[linearc=4, linewidth=0.5pt]{->}(4,4)(3,5)(2.8,6.46)
        \psline[linearc=4, linewidth=0.5pt]{->}(4,4)(3,5)(2.28,5.4)

        \psPoint(0,0,8.8){L}
        \uput[l](L){$v$ konstan}

        \psline[linearc=0.4, linewidth=0.5pt]{->}(-2,7.1)(-2,4.6)
        \psline[linearc=0.4, linewidth=0.5pt]{->}(-2,7.1)(-1.2,4.2)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The screenshot of the result using **XeLatexTRmk**  is

[image]

While the intended result using **LaTexTRmk**, commenting the XeLatex specific lines like `mathspec` etc; will give:

[image]

So I tried copy-paste my code to **overleaf.com** and using XeLatex there (the menu indicates that TexLive 2021 is in use), and the result is fine as above (of course, I also uploaded all the Times fonts).

Using **TexMaker** and **XeLatex** engine in TexShop would produce the same result as following:

[image]

While using TexMaker and opted to view the PS file (instead of PDF), will invoke generating pdf files on **Preview.App** and the result is inconsistence (at some point it achieved fine result, otherwise error filename.ps cannot be converted to pdf)

Using command-line

```
xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" -no-pdf filename.tex
```

also not working.

I have also checked that all my packages are up to date.

This problem appears on all documents using pstricks, the picture produced is sometimes correct, but it always changes the background to white (no transparency)

Picture produced using tikz is fine.

Is there any fix for this? I'm guessing this only effects OS X users.

Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: It is _not_ a good idea to use `pst-solides3d` and `pst-3dplot`. They are far different and can interact in a negative way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to run it with `lualatex`, which, of course, needs some time for the calculation, but it doesn't use GhostScript and creates directly the pdf:

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d,pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\definecolor{ath}{RGB}{247,246,233}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{ath}

We will plot the surface
\[
\mathbf{r}(u, v)=\langle(2+\sin v) \cos u,(2+\sin v) \sin u, u+\cos v\rangle
\]
\begin{center}
\psset{unit=0.5}
\begin{pspicture}*(-5,-4)(6,14)
        \psset{viewpoint=15 10 15, Decran=20}
        
        \defFunction[algebraic]{hega}(u,v){(2+sin(v))*cos(u)} {(2+sin(v))*sin(u)} {u+cos(v)}
        \psSolid[object=surfaceparametree , base=0  12.6 0 8, color1=Red!50,
        color2=Green!20, inouthue=(color1) (color2), function=hega, linewidth=0.3\pslinewidth, 
        ngrid=40 0.3]
        \axesIIID[linewidth=0.5pt , arrowsize=5pt, arrowinset=0, labelsep=10pt](3,2,9)(6,5,13)
        \psPoint(1,3,6.3){I}
        \uput[r](I){$u$ konstan}

        \psline[linearc=4, linewidth=0.5pt]{->}(4,4)(3,5)(2.8,6.46)
        \psline[linearc=4, linewidth=0.5pt]{->}(4,4)(3,5)(2.28,5.4)

        \psPoint(0,0,8.8){L}
        \uput[l](L){$v$ konstan}

        \psline[linearc=0.4, linewidth=0.5pt]{->}(-2,7.1)(-2,4.6)
        \psline[linearc=0.4, linewidth=0.5pt]{->}(-2,7.1)(-1.2,4.2)
    \end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well, this works!  I think I'm going to migrate to lualatex for  a while. Thanks