# ps2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY

Tags: pstricks, transparency

This is just a simple question. I saw [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591533/pstricks-doesnt-compile-anymore-since-mactex-2021-upgrade-on-mac-m1) about the discussion on allowing transparency. I am actually creating documents with PSTricks figures.

My question is: Where do I put or write ps2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY in my LaTeX document? I honestly was not able to follow the thread in the comments on the link above. I am using **TeXStudio** as my TeX editor and uses XeLaTeX to compile documents.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pstricks,pstricks-add}
\usepackage[width=8.29in, height=11.64in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscircle[ fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=green!15 , opacity = 0.95 ](0,0){1}
\pspolygon[  fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=magenta!15 , opacity = 0.95](0,2)(-1,0)(1,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `-dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` is an option that you must add to the ps2pdf call, not to the document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but does `xelatex` run `ps2pdf` behind the scenes?

Comment: @daleif ah sorry I didn't see the reference to xelatex, yes behind the scene it is there too. Adding something like `-output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E"`  to the xelatex call should work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer just checked, it does seem to work.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer where can I find the ps2pdf call? ^^

Comment: It is part of the xdvipdfmx process (I'd presume). Just run `xelatex` as `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E` in your editor

Comment: @daleif I did but the transparency is still not yet fixed.

Comment: is your tex system up-to-date? What messages do you get in the terminal?

Comment: The message says %%%% WARNING: Transparency operations ignored - need to use -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY
Process exited normally

I am using MacTex 2023 in case it helps solve the situation.

Comment: Works just fine for me on the command line (try that before mosing to your editor). When viewing the PDF, I can see the edge of the circle through the purple triangle.

Comment: mactex can be special. I think texshop has some special engines for this but as I don't have a mac I can check. Or try with lualatex, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/634809/2388

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `lualatex` instead of `xelatex`. Then you do not need `ps2pdf`:

[image]

image with `opacity=0.5`

Comment: This works fine! Thank you so much. I have another question. If I load the pst-pdf package, the PSTricks image disappears but if I do not use, some texts are missing and the PSTricks image is incomplete. How do I deal with this one?

Comment: give an example! There is only a known problem with filled outline font.

Comment: I seem to have fixed it just now. The packages pst-3dplot and pst-pdf cause the PSTricks image to not display.

Comment: with `lualatex` you do not need the package `pst-pdf`!!

Comment: the example exhibiting the problem is on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700140/incomplete-missing-pstricks-image