# Incomplete/Missing PSTricks Image

Tags: xetex, luatex, pstricks, graphs

**EDITED:** I am trying to make the diagram illustrating the ε-δ definition of limits and some other 3D plot but the 2D plot seems to be incomplete while the 3D graph is not visible. I am using **LuaLaTeX** (due to opacity/transparency issues) to compile my document.

The following is the MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}

    
\usepackage[width=8.29in, height=11.64in, left=0.5in,right=0.5in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath ,amsfonts , amssymb}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage[pageanchor, pdfpagelabels , hyperfigures , hyperindex,  ]{hyperref}  % hidelinks  : to hide the box links
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{rotating}



 \begin{document}



 \begin{center}
 \psset{xunit=1.30cm,yunit=1.30cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2, }  % arrowinset=0.25

\begin{pspicture}(-1.16,-0.7)(5.00,5.25)     \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,labels=none,Dx=1,Dy=1,ticksize=0pt 0,subticks=0,showorigin=false]{->}(0,0)(-1.16,-0.7)(4.5,3.75)[$x$,0] [$y$,90]          
\pspolygon[linestyle = none , fillstyle=solid , fillcolor=green!15 , opacity=0.5 ](1.65 , 2.3333)(2.35 , 2.3333)(2.35, 1.6666)(1.65 , 1.6666)
\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red,dash=4pt 2pt](1.2489 , 0)(1.2489 , 1.6666)   
\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red,dash=4pt 2pt](3.5,0)(3.5 , 2.33333)   
\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red,dash=4pt 2pt](0, 2.33333)(3.5 , 2.33333)   
\parametricplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1pt]{0.5}{4}{ t |   (2*(t) + 8)  /  ( - 2*(t) - 2 )  +  4  }
\rput[b](3.6,2.5){{\normalsize\rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{\blue{$ y = f(x) $}}}}
\rput[b](-0.5,3.0){$L+\varepsilon$}
\rput[r](-0.10,2.0){$L$}
\rput[t](-0.5,1.0){$L-\varepsilon$}
\rput[t](1.2589,-0.15){$x_0$}
\rput[t](3.5,-0.15){$x_1$}
\rput[t](1.5,-0.45){$a - \delta$}
\rput[t](2,-0.1){$a$}
\rput[tl](2.5,-0.45){$a + \delta$}    
\psline[linestyle=solid, linewidth= 0.5pt, linecolor=black ,dash=4pt 2pt, arrows = <- ](2.35,-0.05)(2.75,-0.40)   
\psline[linestyle=solid, linewidth= 0.5pt, linecolor=black ,dash=4pt 2pt, arrows = <- ](1.65,-0.05)(1.5,-0.43)   
\psline[linestyle=solid, linewidth= 0.5pt, linecolor=black,dash=4pt 2pt, arrows = <- ](0, 2.3333)(-0.50,2.95)   
\psline[linestyle=solid, linewidth= 0.5pt, linecolor=black,dash=4pt 2pt, arrows = <- ](0, 1.6666)(-0.50,1.05)   
\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue,dash=4pt 2pt](2,2)(2,0)   
\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue,dash=4pt 2pt](0,2)(2,2)
\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=red,dash=4pt 2pt](0,1.6666)(2.35, 1.66666)               
\psdots[linecolor=blue,fillcolor=white,dotstyle=*,dotsize=4.5pt](2,2)  
\psdots[linecolor=blue,fillcolor=white,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3.5pt](2,2)  
\psdots[dotstyle=*,dotsize=2.0pt](2,0)  
\psline[linestyle=solid,linecolor=blue, linewidth=2pt](1.65,0)(2.35,0)          
\psline[linestyle=solid,linecolor=red, linewidth=2pt](0, 1.65)(0, 2.33333)   
\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue,dash=4pt 2pt](2.35,0)(2.35,2.33333)   
            
\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue,dash=4pt 2pt](1.65 , 0 )(1.65 , 2.33333)                
\end{pspicture} 
\end{center}

\psset{Alpha=75,unit=2}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.6,-1)(2,2)
\psset{arrowscale=1.5,arrowinset=0,dotstyle=*,dotscale=1.5,drawCoor}
\pstThreeDCoor[linecolor=black,xMin=-0.5,xMax=2,yMin=-0.5,yMax=2,zMin=-0.5,zMax=2]
\pstThreeDLine[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](1.5,0,0)(0,1.5,0)
\pstThreeDLine[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](0,1.5,0)(0,0,1.5)
\pstThreeDLine[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed](0,0,1.5)(1.5,0,0)

\pstThreeDDot[linecolor=blue]( 1.5 ,0 , 0)
\pstThreeDDot[linecolor=blue]( 0 ,1.5 , 0)
\pstThreeDDot[linecolor=blue]( 0 ,0 , 1.5)
\pstThreeDPut(1.5,0.1,-0.1){$\sqrt{E_s}$}
\pstThreeDPut(0.1,1.5,-0.1){$\sqrt{E_s}$}
\pstThreeDPut(0.1,-0.1,1.6){$\sqrt{E_s}$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

When using TeXStudio, the image renders like this:

[image]

and the 3D graph is missing; however, when I compile using TeXMaker, the image renders like this:
[image]
along with the 3D graph.

The logfile in TeXStudio is the following:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023)  (format=lualatex 2023.10.31)  2 NOV 2023 00:38
 restricted system commands enabled.
**document.tex
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
Lua module: luaotfload 2022-10-03 3.23 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2022-10-04 2.75 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2022-10-04 2.75 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/Users/*******/Library/texli
ve/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2022-10-03.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-
2022-10-03.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 3.120
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 2
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/Users/*******/Library/texli
ve/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_opentype_file'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.strip_prefix' in `find_truetype_file'.
Removing  `luaotfload.glyph_stream' from `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.glyphstream' in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_vlist' in `post_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_hlist' in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.cleanup_files' in `wrapup_run'.
Inserting `luaotfload.harf.finalize_unicode' in `finish_pdffile'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyphinfo' in `glyph_info'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload.letterspace_done = 3
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' in `luaotfload.patch_font_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' in `luaotfload.patch_font'. L3 programm
ing layer <2023-02-22>
Inserting `tracingstacklevels' in `input_level_string'.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfmanagement-testphase/pdfmanage
ment-testphase.sty
Package: pdfmanagement-testphase 2023-03-09 v0.95x LaTeX PDF management testpha
se bundle

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tagpdf/tagpdf-base.sty
Package: tagpdf-base 2023-03-07 v0.98e part of tagpdf - provide base, no-op ver
sions of the user commands 
\c@g__tag_struct_abs_int=\count183
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfmanagement-testphase/pdfmanage
ment-testphase.ltx
File: pdfmanagement-testphase.ltx 2023-03-09 v0.95x PDF management code (testph
ase)
\g__pdfmanagement_EmbeddedFiles_int=\count184

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental/l3bitset/l3bitset.
sty
Package: l3bitset 2023-01-24 L3 Experimental bitset support
\l__bitset_internal_int=\count185
)
\l__pdfmeta_xmp_indent_int=\count186
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latex-lab/documentmetadata-suppor
t.ltx)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def
File: l3backend-luatex.def 2023-01-16 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count187
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfmanagement-testphase/l3backend
-testphase-luatex.def
File: l3backend-testphase-luatex.def 2023-03-09 LaTeX PDF management testphase 
bundle backend support:PDFoutput(LuaTeX)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfmanagement-testphase/l3ref-tmp
.sty
Package: l3ref-tmp 2021-06-23 L3 Experimental cross-referencing
)
\l__pdf_backend_tmpa_box=\box52
\l__pdf_backend_tmpb_box=\box53
\g__pdf_backend_resourceid_int=\count188
\g__pdf_backend_name_int=\count189
\g__pdf_backend_page_int=\count190
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfmanagement-testphase/pdfmanage
ment-firstaid.sty
Package: pdfmanagement-firstaid 2023-03-09 v0.95x LaTeX PDF management testphas
e bundle / firstaid-patches

Package pdfmanagement Info: loading pdfmanagement firstaid code for pgf

)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /Users/*******/Library/
texlive/2023/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc.gz)
\c@part=\count191
\c@chapter=\count192
\c@section=\count193
\c@subsection=\count194
\c@subsubsection=\count195
\c@paragraph=\count196
\c@subparagraph=\count197
\c@figure=\count198
\c@table=\count199
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen139
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
\Gm@cnth=\count266
\Gm@cntv=\count267
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count268
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen140
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen141
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen142
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen143
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen144
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen145
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen146
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen147
\Gm@dimlist=\toks17


Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
    `width' (599.11781pt) is ignored.


Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
    `height' (841.22275pt) is ignored.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2022/04/08 v2.17n AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\ex@=\dimen148
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen149
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count269
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 236.
\uproot@=\count270
\leftroot@=\count271
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count272
\DOTSCASE@=\count273
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box54
\strutbox@=\box55
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen150
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count274
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count275
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count276
\dspbrk@lvl=\count277
\tag@help=\toks19
\row@=\count278
\column@=\count279
\maxfields@=\count280
\andhelp@=\toks20
\eqnshift@=\dimen151
\alignsep@=\dimen152
\tagshift@=\dimen153
\tagwidth@=\dimen154
\totwidth@=\dimen155
\lineht@=\dimen156
\@envbody=\toks21
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks22
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/draftwatermark/draftwatermark.sty
Package: draftwatermark 2020/12/08 3.0 Put a gray textual watermark on document
 pages
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 107.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def
File: luatex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2d Graphics/color driver for luatex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen157
\Gin@req@width=\dimen158
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfmanagement-testphase/color-ltx
.sty
Package: color-ltx 2023-03-09 v0.95x Standard LaTeX Color (patched for l3color,
 part of pdfmanagement-testphase, original version 2022/01/06 v1.3d) (DPC)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 165.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty
Package: enumitem 2019/06/20 v3.9 Customized lists
\labelindent=\skip53
\enit@outerparindent=\dimen159
\enit@toks=\toks23
\enit@inbox=\box56
\enit@count@id=\count281
\enitdp@description=\count282
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2023-02-07 v7.00v Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
\pdftexcmds@toks=\toks24
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2022-05-17 v2.50 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.s
ty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count283
)
\@linkdim=\dimen160
\Hy@linkcounter=\count284
\Hy@pagecounter=\count285
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2023-02-07 v7.00v Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count286

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2023-02-07 v7.00v Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `pageanchor' set `true' on input line 4060.
Package hyperref Info: Option `pdfpagelabels' set `true' on input line 4060.
Package hyperref Info: Option `hyperfigures' set `true' on input line 4060.
Package hyperref Info: Option `hyperindex' set `true' on input line 4060.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures ON on input line 4175.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4182.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4185.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4192.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4197.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4425.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count287

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4763.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen161

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count288
\Field@Width=\dimen162
\Fld@charsize=\dimen163
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures ON on input line 6040.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6047.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6050.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6057.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6062.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6067.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6072.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count289
\c@Item=\count290
\c@Hfootnote=\count291
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (custom): hgeneric-testphase.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfmanagement-testphase/hgeneric-
testphase.def
File: hgeneric-testphase.def 2023-03-09 v0.95x generic Hyperref driver for the 
LaTeX PDF management testphase bundle

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count292
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfmanagement-testphase/hyperref-
colorschemes.def)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \href on input line 274.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 360.
\l__hyp_tmpa_box=\box57
\l__hyp_tmpa_int=\count293
\l__hyp_dest_box=\box58
\HyAnn@Count=\count294
\Fld@listcount=\count295
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip54
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Hy__hypSectionAnchor on input line 3451.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
Package: pstricks 2022/19/23 v0.72 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: luatex.def on input line 227.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \color on input line 711.

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1375.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfmanagement-testphase/xcolor-pa
tches-tmp-ltx.sty
Package: xcolor-patches-tmp-ltx 2023-03-09 v0.95x patch xcolor for l3color
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks25
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks26
)
\XKV@depth=\count296
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.06, 2020/11/20 (hv)
\pstFP@xs=\count297
\pstFP@xia=\count298
\pstFP@xib=\count299
\pstFP@xfa=\count300
\pstFP@xfb=\count301
\pstFP@rega=\count302
\pstFP@regb=\count303
\pstFP@regs=\count304
\pstFP@times=\count305
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks27
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen164
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen165
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box59
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks28
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks29

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfil
tered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks30
```

May I know what causes the error and how to fix it?
Thank you.

Comment: No problem here with an up-to-date TL23. Show your log file

Comment: @user187802 It seems to compile well in TexMaker but not in TeXStudio.

Comment: @thenerdymathematician what exactly do you mean by `compile well` in TeXMaker but not in TeXStudio? Are there errors? if so please post them? Do they render the PDF differently in their PDF viewers?

Comment: I get a compilation error on line 83, what is this suppose to mean: `\psline[linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue,dash=4pt 2pt](2,2(2,0)   `? I assume it should end with `(2,2)(2,0)`. Perhaps you should add a screen shot from both editors, so others can see what this is suppose to look like.

Comment: texmaker and texstudio are just editors neither compile the document at all, they just call your underlying tex system. It maybe that you have two systems installed one with and one without pstricks, but the editor is not related.  Do you _really_ use all those packages??? You should certainly not include them in a test example here as it just makes it harder for people to trace tex and answer your question.

Comment: don't load `etex` package unless your latex system is 20 years old. Depending on package loading order it will either warn that it will do nothing, or will change things and break latex.

Comment: Ahh, running `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` I can see that a lot is missing under `lualatex`. Please add images.

Comment: It works under `xelatex` via `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" imf.tex`

Comment: @daleif In TeXStudio, it compiles the image this way: https://app.gemoo.com/share/image-annotation/578350967689428992?codeId=M0GpoxEVlrqAR&origin=imageurlgenerator

However, in TeXMaker, the output is this: https://app.gemoo.com/share/image-annotation/578351310510854144?codeId=vJRdp88LXy4E1&origin=imageurlgenerator

Comment: Please add the images to your question. We generally do not like to go to random websites.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are using `lualatex` in both cases? See the log file, it is listed at the very top.

Comment: @daleif I have edited my post along with the images ^^

And yes, I am using **lualatex** in both editors.

There are some transparency/opacity issues with xelatex that is why I resorted to *lualatex*.

Comment: Shorten your preamble. I refuse to test your document in the state it is now. This is simply unfriendly to dump such a document on people from whom you want to get help.

Comment: You should show the _logfile_

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did. ^__^

Comment: remove more. For every package check if it is really needed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I followed your advice. I just came down to the following packages:

\usepackage[width=8.29in, height=11.64in, left=0.5in,right=0.5in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath ,amsfonts , amssymb}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pageanchor, pdfpagelabels , hyperfigures , hyperindex,  ]{hyperref}  % hidelinks  : to hide the box links
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\usepackage{rotating}

The problem is from the draftwatermark package. Is it possible to use it?

Comment: That is not the log file, it is only the list of messages from the logfile. Click on the right button "Log file" and the copy and paste the output, mainly the first 50 lines.

Comment: @user187802 Just did it, thank you.

Comment: Those are not the first lines. The first 3 lines lists the LaTeX installates and format version. Do you by any change have two LaTeX installations? Again the start of the log files from each will tell.

Comment: Yes. but it doesn't show the beginning of the latex run. You have to scroll on top of the output and then copy the beginning.

Comment: @user187802 Just did. Thank you. ^^

Comment: Looks good and I suppose that you have a problem with the viewer. Do not use the internal pdf-viewer of TeXStudio, use the external one (can be set in the preferences). If you already had this, then open a terminal and insert "open <file>.pdf"

Comment: And, by the way: Update your TeX distribution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well somewhere in the depth of `pst-3dplot.tex` (around line 2420) the code redefines some commands from the trig package for sinus and cosinus used by graphics to rotate boxes.

And this means that something like this (when compiled with lualatex):

```
\DocumentMetadata{uncompress} 
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{0}{abc} 
\end{document}
```

produces nonsense in the middle of pdf because the values no longer expand correctly:

```
1 0 0 1 148.712 657.235 cm
q
\cos(0)  \sin(0)  -\sin(0)  \cos(0) warning  (pdf backend): unrecognized format of setmatrix: \cos(0)  \sin(0)  -\sin(0)  \cos(0)  0 0 cm
1 0 0 1 -148.712 -657.235 cm
```

And every decent PDF viewer is quite right to choke over this.

As a work around load `pst-3dplot` earlier and report the problem to the pstricks maintainer.

Comment: putting the `pst-3dplot` package earlier indeed solves the problem! Really big thanks. ^^

Comment: "% stolen from the trig.sty package by David Carlisle" but not updated when trig.sty changed

Comment: do not forget to report the bug!